# pgfplots: xtick, xticklabels and extra x ticks

Tags: pgfplots

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xtick = {0,1,5},
        xticklabels = {{zero},$\alpha$,$\varphi$},
        extra x ticks = {-4,-2},
        extra x tick style = {
                            red,
                            font=\bfseries
                            },
    ]
    \addplot {x^2 - x +4};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

- I use `xtick` with custom labels (`xticklabels`).
- In addition, I want some `extra x ticks`.
- I expect that the `extra x ticks` are printed automatically but instead, the `xticklabels` are used.
- I did not define `extra x tick labels`.

Comment: I consider this being a bug which I added to the [PGFPlots Tracker](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/160/). Good catch!

Comment: @StefanPinnow Thanks for the reply. Your code additions are helpful.

Comment: I am a little bit confused. Can you assign `xtick={0,1,5,-4,-2}`?

Comment: @Symbol1 I am not sure that I understand your comment. Surely there is a work around, if that's what you mean. I am more concerned about the unexpected behavior.

Comment: IMHO, there is no **expected behavior**. If I were the package author, I would expect the user to assign `xtick` in just one place and assign `xticklabels` in just one place. The only scenario that the `extra` part is useful is when `xtick=something automatic` and `extra x ticks=something manual`. Anyway, this is quite unexpected because I looked into the source code and I cannot find out where is this logic implemented.

Comment: @Symbol1 Ok. Maybe we have different expectations (no problem). Instead of the red text I would expect `$-4$` and `$-2$`. But let's just see whet the developer has to say about the "bug" report.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the bug was solved in PGFPlots v1.15

Comment: @StefanPinnow Alright :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignore my comment

In `pgfplots.code.tex` line 6888-90

> ```
>   \expandafter\ifx\csname pgfplots@extra@#1ticklabel\endcsname\pgfutil@empty 
>       \pgfutil@namelet{pgfplots@extra@#1ticklabel}{pgfplots@#1ticklabel}% 
>   \fi
> ```

This shows that this is intentionally designed to use `xticklables` as fallback of `extra x tick labels`.

The workaround is simple, assign `extra x tick label` or `extra x tick labels`.

## The expected behavior

@Dr. Manuel Kuehner suggests that the expected behavior is to simply print the x-coordinate. This makes more sense than I thought. In that case, we should replace the three lines by the following

```
\expandafter\ifx\csname pgfplots@extra@#1ticklabel\endcsname\pgfutil@empty
    \expandafter\def\csname pgfplots@extra@#1ticklabel\endcsname{\axisdefaultticklabel}%
\fi
```

By **replace**, I mean to edit `pgfplots.code.tex` or to redefine `\pgfplots@init@ticks@for#1`.

---

By the way, in the same file, if we look at line 6881-90, we see

> ```
> \expandafter\ifx\csname pgfplots@#1ticklabel\endcsname\pgfutil@empty
>   \pgfplots@if{pgfplots@#1islinear}{%
>       \expandafter\def\csname pgfplots@#1ticklabel\endcsname{\axisdefaultticklabel}%
>   }{%
>       \expandafter\def\csname pgfplots@#1ticklabel\endcsname{\axisdefaultticklabellog}%
>   }% 
> \fi
> \expandafter\ifx\csname pgfplots@extra@#1ticklabel\endcsname\pgfutil@empty
>   \pgfutil@namelet{pgfplots@extra@#1ticklabel}{pgfplots@#1ticklabel}%
> \fi
> ```

translate to English

- if the user does not assign how to print normal labels, simply print the x-coordinate
- if the user does assign how to print normal labels, obey the user.
- if the user does not assign how to print extra labels, treat extra labels as they are normal labels.

The logic behind is that, sometimes the user prefers **0cm**, **1cm**, and **5cm** rather than `0`, `1`, and `5`. So the user may assign

```
xticklabel={$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}$cm}
```

In this case, the user probably want **-4cm** and **-2cm** instead of `-4` and `-2`, so PGFPlots will inherit the formatting and add **cm** to extra labels.

---

So the problem is, how to implement the following logic?

- if the user does not assign how to print normal labels, simply print the x-coordinate
- if the user does assign how to print normal labels, obey the user.
- if the user does not assign how to print extra labels:

  - if the user assign `xticklabel`, treat extra labels as they are normal labels.
  - if the user assign `xticklabels`, simply print the x-coordinate.

You probably want to check if `\pgfplots@xticklabel` is empty. (Do you?)

Comment: Thanks for the workaround! I still think that this is not (at least my) expected behavior. But your code provides a solution.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: I updated the answer, I hope I can give as much information as you need.

Comment: Wow -- a very elaborate answer. Thanks for the deep dive into the `pgfplots` code. The `xticklabel=$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}$cm}` might be useful in the future :).

Comment: Thanks for the good pre-analysis, @Symbol1. I have fixed the issue in the codebase along your suggested definition (which solves the issue at hand and is the best default that I can think of).